# Swift - alert action handler error

Tags: ios, swift, handler, alert, flurry

I have some strange stuff going on: trying to track if a share action was cancelled in UIAlertAction handler with FLurry Analytics SDK. The code should basically look like that:

```
       let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: {
            (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            Flurry.logEvent("Share Cancelled")
            }
        )
```

But compiler shows an error "Extra argument "title" in call..." and highlights "Cancel" in red.
Though if I add any variable declaration or simple function like println() than there is no error! i.e. this code is compiled correctly and considered to be working:

```
       let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: {
            (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            let somevar = 0
            Flurry.logEvent("Share Cancelled")
            }
        )
```

Have anyone faced a thing like that? Maybe it's a Swift or Flurry bug?

Comment: Swift has terrible error reporting, but it might be trying to infer the return type from a single line closure.  Check the return type of logEvent, to see if it is void, as (I assume) UIAlertView's expects closure returning Void.  Your point remains though, about the misleading error.  The normal way to fix this (if my premise is correct), is to add a single line return on the last line.

Comment: Wow, couldn't even think about it... But the return type of logEvent is really not void. So single line return (w/o any actual value returned) works pretty fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sake of resolution, from my previous comment, Swift will try to infer the return type from a closure with a single statement.  If you are trying to define a closure with a single statement that has a return value, then Swift will assume that to be the return value for your closure.

Since you noted that logEvent returns a value, you will need to explicitly return nothing at all, to create the proper closure.

For what it's worth, this appears to be changed / fixed in 6.3, as the following code now executes:

```
func foo() -> Int {
    return 1
}

func bar(() -> ()) {
    println("Hello from bar")
}

bar({ foo() })
```

In general, the way to debug ambiguous errors like this, is to break the statement into multiple lines, explicitly defining expected types at each stage, and watch where it breaks.

Comment: Thanks for a thorough explanation!